# Python: Routine for handling API request limits

Tags: python, api, httprequest

I need to make a lot of HTTP requests (> 1000) against a public service which only allows 500 HTTP requests per day. Hence, I have to count the number of executed requests and stop when I reach the maximum daily amount to continue the next day with the remaining calls. In particular, I iterate over a non-sorted list, so I cannot assume that the elements are in any order. My code looks like this:

```
from requests import Session, Request

request_parameters = {'api_key': api_key}

for user_id in all_user_ids:
    r = requests.get('http://public-api.com/%s'% user_id, request_parameters)
    text = r.content
    # do some stuff with text
```

Is there any package or pattern which you can recommend for counting and resuming API calls like this?

Comment: The problem is that even if I count myself, the elements I am iterating over might not be in the same order as before which makes it difficult to resume the next day

Comment: I am asking because I do not see an efficient way to log the executed calls so that I know where to continue the next day

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest implementing a simple counter to stop when you have hit your limit for the day along with a local cache of the data you have already received. Then when you run the process again the next day check each record against your local cache first and only go on to call the web service if there is no record in the local cache. That way you will eventually have all of the data unless you are generating more requests per day than the service usage limit.

The format of the cache will depend on what is returned from the web service and how much of that data you need, but it may be as simple as a csv file with a unique identifier to search against and the other fields you will need to retrieve in future.

Another option would be to store the whole response from each call (if you need a lot of it) in a dictionary with the key being a unique identifier and the value being the response. This could be saved as a json file and easily loaded back into memory for checking against on future runs.